# Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/---

Tags: java, maven, jboss, ejb, wildfly

Below is my maven configuration

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce.brewtique</groupId>
    <artifactId>BrewtiqueProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modules>
        <module>ejb</module>
        <module>ear</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
```

And children pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce</groupId>
    <artifactId>TrBrewCommerce</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>TrBrewCommerce</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.koinplus</groupId>  
       <artifactId>KoinPlusCommons</artifactId>  
       <version>1.0</version> 
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>C://Users/trbrewjars/KoinPlusCommons-1.0.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.trbrew.common</groupId>  
       <artifactId>TrBrewCommons</artifactId>  
       <version>1.0</version> 
       <scope>system</scope>
       <systemPath>C://Users/trbrewjars/TrendBrewCommons-1.0.jar</systemPath>
     </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Pom of ear module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>BrewtiqueProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.tbrew.commerce.brewtique</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>Brewtique</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce.brewtique</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce.brewtique</groupId>
            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>-->
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce.brewtique</groupId>
                            <artifactId>web</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce.brewtique</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Pom of ejb module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>BrewtiqueProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce.brewtique</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trbrew.commerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>TrBrewCommerce</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and the error I ran into while running the ear file generated is

```
17:31:09,694 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Brewtique-1.0.ear"."ejb-1.0.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Brewtique-1.0.ear"."ejb-1.0.jar".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "ejb-1.0.jar" of deployment "Brewtique-1.0.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/trendbrew/commerce/brewtique/catalog/CatalogManagementService (Module "deployment.Brewtique-1.0.ear.ejb-1.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/koinplus/common/GenericKoinPlusService
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.koinplus.common.GenericKoinPlusService from [Module "deployment.Brewtique-1.0.ear.ejb-1.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
        ... 23 more

17:31:09,725 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment web-1.0.war
17:31:09,804 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Brewtique-1.0.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".\"ejb-1.0.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".\"ejb-1.0.jar\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"ejb-1.0.jar\" of deployment \"Brewtique-1.0.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/trendbrew/commerce/brewtique/catalog/CatalogManagementService (Module \"deployment.Brewtique-1.0.ear.ejb-1.0.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/koinplus/common/GenericKoinPlusService
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.koinplus.common.GenericKoinPlusService from [Module \"deployment.Brewtique-1.0.ear.ejb-1.0.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".\"web-1.0.war\".batch.environment is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear\".\"web-1.0.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Brewtique-1.0.ear/ejb-1.0.jar#tbCommPersistence\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasource.wishinity]",
```

The ear file deployed on Wildfly and not able to crack the reason. Any clues ?

Tried reinstall ... repackage, maven update/refresh with no luck.

Comment: Can you show children pom.xml of EAR and projects using GenericKoinPlusService ?

Comment: @davidhxxx Thanks for responding. Add the requested pom.

Comment: I also need the pom of this module : <module>ear</module> :)

Comment: @davidhxxx Added that too :) hope that helps.

Comment: It begins :) Can you show the pom of the EJB  ? It is the culprit in the stacktrace. You should also open your EAR file and check that the `KoinPlusCommons-1.0.jar` file is present in the lib folder

Comment: @davidhxxx Added it :) And I just unpacked and checked for the jsr, NOO it is not there :( do I need to place the jar there and then pack it back .. hectic job each time it seems ..please help.

Comment: I will do a answer to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.koinplus</groupId>  
   <artifactId>KoinPlusCommons</artifactId>  
   <version>1.0</version> 
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>C://Users/trbrewjars/KoinPlusCommons-1.0.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.trbrew.common</groupId>  
   <artifactId>TrBrewCommons</artifactId>  
   <version>1.0</version> 
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>C://Users/trbrewjars/TrendBrewCommons-1.0.jar</systemPath>
 </dependency>
```

you declare your dependencies with a `system` scope. 
It prevents you from having these dependencies in the resolution of the TrBrewCommerce artifact and so in your final EAR artifact.
If you want that these jars to be included in your EAR, using tricks to keep  `system` scope is not a clean build.
A cleaner way of doing is installing these two jars in your maven repository.
After, you could remove the scope `system` (in this case, scope `runtime` will be used by default) and the system path in the dependency declaration such as:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.koinplus</groupId>  
   <artifactId>KoinPlusCommons</artifactId>  
   <version>1.0</version> 
 </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.trbrew.common</groupId>  
   <artifactId>TrBrewCommons</artifactId>  
   <version>1.0</version> 
 </dependency>
```

To install a Maven artifact, you have the `install-file` goal :

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: Thankyou. Maven is always a nightmare to me :)

Comment: It's a pleasure :) When you do no conventional things, Maven may become a nightmare indeed. That's why I intentionally gave  you a solution to keep more Maven friendly rather that a solution based on tricks because `system  scope` is often a trick ;-)